# "Had" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

*He had a sister*. Or *He had two daughters*.

Does having *had* in the sentence mean that that his sister is dead? Does the word *had* used in such way always imply the death of the respective person?

Comment: Without context it could mean lots of things

Answer (score 1):

No, it is just in the past tense.

Compare *I met him last year. He had a sister. Now he has two sisters!*

Comment: It _could_ mean she is dead, "He had a sister, but sadly she passed away." Or that he is dead, "He had a sister but she isn't here today."

Comment: Yes, it could mean quite a lot of things :) But it does not _always_ have that meaning, as the OP asked for.